# Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract class override

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides

As title suggest i want to override `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` class , I know that it is `abstract class`. and we can easily override abstract class using local directory like `app\code\local\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Abstract.php`. But i want to know is there any other option for me ? Because this option is not safe with different magento version.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overwrite Abstract class](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228068/overwrite-abstract-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For abstract classes, there is not other way to rewrite them, other than copying them to the `local` folder.
The abstract classes are never instantiated and you can rewrite only the classes that get instantiated.

To go a little more technical, you can rewrite only the classes that are instantiated using factory methods like `Mage::getModel`, `Mage::getSingleton`, `Mage::getResourceModel`, `Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock()`, `Mage::helper` and so on.

The abstract classes are there just as a common ancestor for other classes.
Here is an example.

```
abstract class A {}
class B extends A{}
class C extends A {}
```

Even if you rewrite the class `A` using the standard way of rewriting, classes `B` and `C` will still extend the original class `A` so your rewrite is useless.
The only way you can change class `A` is to make the autoloader retrieve it from a different location.
That's why you need to move it to the `local` (or `community` folder).

you can get more info about this "issue" [from here](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2011/09/why-cant-you-override-some-classes-in.html)

Comment: is create any issue if i use this method different version of magento? @Marius

Comment: @KeyurShah. Well, there is the chance that on a future upgrade something will fail. But if something goes wrong at least you know where to  look.

Comment: @Marius I am trying to override prepareSave function of Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc  model but nothing is working for me. I followed https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172334/magento-cannot-override-mage-payment-model-method-cc-php-file this, it is working fine for isAvailable function but not working for prepareSave function.