# Magento cannot override Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc.php file

Tags: magento-1.9, model, payment

I am trying to override Payment/Model/Method/Cc.php file but it's not able rewrite. can you please any one check my script.

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Naveed_Abbas>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Naveed_Abbas>
   </modules>
<global>
    <models>
       <payment>
            <rewrite>
                <method_cc>Naveed_Abbas_Model_Payment_Method_Cc</method_cc>                    
            </rewrite>
       </payment>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Naveed/Abbas/Model/Payment/Method/Cc.php :

```
<?php
  class Naveed_Abbas_Model_Payment_Method_Cc extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc {

    public function isAvailable($quote = null) {
         Mage::log("Canel Order",null,'isAvailable-test-1.log');
        return $this->getConfigData('cctypes', ($quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null))
        && parent::isAvailable($quote);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Seems perfect. Are you sure its not already overridden by some other module or something else. Code looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @Kingshuk happy to reconnect, Actually i am trying in new instance(just now installed)

Comment: have create `Naveed_Abbas.xml` app/etc/modules

Comment: @Amit, that module is visible in admin panel also with enable status.

Comment: What specific payment method are you trying to affect? `Stored CC`?

Comment: Please check compiler is enabled or not

Comment: @Amit, compiler status is disabled

Comment: @Ryan, Actually i am trying do some changes Credit Card Payment.

Comment: @Ramesh Have you completed </config> tag in your config.xml file

Comment: @Rakesh, i have the tag updated that tag in above

Comment: @Ramesh, I have just updated my answer.

Comment: @Ramesh 'Credit Card Payment' is not a specific payment method. What is the underlying payment gateway, or payment method code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried lot of ways finally i got the solution.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Naveed_Abbas>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Naveed_Abbas>
   </modules>
   <global>
     <models>
        <payment>
          <rewrite>
            <method_ccsave>Naveed_Abbas_Model_Payment_Method_Cc</method_ccsave>
           </rewrite>
        </payment>
     </models>
   </global>
 </config>
```

Naveed/Abbas/Model/Payment/Method/Cc.php :

```
<?php

   class Naveed_Abbas_Model_Payment_Method_Cc extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Ccsave{

      public function isAvailable($quote = null) {
         echo "Test"; //sssssssexit;
         Mage::log("Canel Order",null,'isAvailable-test-1.log'); exit;
         return $this->getConfigData('cctypes', ($quote ? $quote->getStoreId() : null))
        && parent::isAvailable($quote);
     }    
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Explanation is easy here.

There is a class `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` which has a lot of methods. The other class `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Ccsave` is extended from it. It has few protected properties. All methods it takes from it's parent.

When magento is looking for some method from `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Ccsave` and didn't find it there - it goes to it's parent method.

As result you see in xdebug that you are referring to `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc`. But if you look which class is inside `$this` - you will see `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Ccsave`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below way using **`<payment_method_cc>`** in config.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
      <Naveed_Abbas>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
      </Naveed_Abbas>
   </modules>
<global>
    <models>
       <naveed_abbas>
            <class>Naveed_Abbas_Model</class>
       </naveed_abbas>
       <payment>
            <rewrite>
                <payment_method_cc>Naveed_Abbas_Model_Payment_Method_Cc</payment_method_cc>                    
            </rewrite>
       </payment>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

Comment: i updated my xml script with your script but still its going to core file.

Comment: shall i share my module

Comment: Sometimes module does not effect because of compiler enable.

Have you checked compiler is enable or disabled? Also checked cache is disabled.